# Having trouble with jquery each function with if statement

Tags: jquery, each

I'm having trouble with one jquery each function combined with else if statement.

I'm having several inputs with my worktime page . I'd like to display alert everytime if one of the inputs have 00:00 value.

Here's some HTML

```
<div class="fpp-plandnia">
            <div class="fpp-plandnia-item">
                <div class="fpp-godziny-container">
                    <div class="_grid100">
                        <div class="_grid50">
                                <input id="godzina_noiphone_od" type="text" value="07:00">
                        </div>
                        <div class="_grid50 r">
                                <input id="godzina_noiphone_do" type="text" value="15:00">          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

         <div class="fpp-plandnia-item">
                <div class="fpp-godziny-container clearfix">
                    <div class="_grid100">
                        <div class="_grid50">
                                <input id="godzina_noiphone_od" type="text" value="07:00">
                        </div>
                        <div class="_grid50 r">
                                <input id="godzina_noiphone_do" type="text" value="15:00">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

and my script

```
$('.fpp-plandnia-item div.fpp-godziny-container').each(function(){

   var a = $(this).find('div._grid50 input#godzina_noiphone_od').val()
   var b = $(this).find('div._grid50.r input#godzina_noiphone_do').val()

   if ((a === '00:00') || (b === '00:00')) {      
    alert('Hour times can not be 00:00');        
   } else {        
     Save();            
   }     
});
```

No it displays alert but does not prevent Save() function.

Many thanks for your help.

Best

Maciej

Comment: Try adding a return; after alert line.

Comment: Are you sure that `Save()` is called when either input is '00:00'? Add `console.log` to verify

Comment: adding return didn't help.

Comment: When I add console.log(Save()) to code I got false in console

Comment: Other think is that if I put // Save() in code then it doesn't save so this is the function that saves changes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Now it works like a charm

```
var time_test = false;


$('.fpp-plandnia-item div.fpp-godziny-container').each(function(){

     var a = $(this).find('div._grid50 input#godzina_noiphone_od').val()
   var b = $(this).find('div._grid50.r input#godzina_noiphone_do').val()


    if ((a === '00:00') || (b === '00:00')) {
        time_test = true;
    } else {
        //
    }

});


if (time_test) {

    alert('Hour times can not be 00:00');

} else {

    Save();
}
```